# How to create a webview in Titanium that renders a g.raphael pie chart with static data?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, raphael

I tried to incorporate g.raphael pie within a webview in Titanium using g.raphael pie example.  But when i run the code on the iOS simulator it only displays a page with no chart but display the labels just fine.

> "Pie chart with legend, hyperlinks on two first sectors and hover
>   effect."

below is the g.raphael code on my chart.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>

        <script src="raphael.lib"></script>
        <script src="g.raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="g.pie.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var r = Raphael("holder"),
                    pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], { legend: ["%%.%% - Enterprise Users", "IE Users"], legendpos: "west", href: ["http://raphaeljs.com", "http://g.raphaeljs.com"]});

                r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
                pie.hover(function () {
                    this.sector.stop();
                    this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);

                    if (this.label) {
                        this.label[0].stop();
                        this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
                        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
                    }
                }, function () {
                    this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");

                    if (this.label) {
                        this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "bounce");
                        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="raphael" id="g.raphael.dmitry.baranovskiy.com">
        <div id="holder"></div>
        <p>
            Pie chart with legend, hyperlinks on two first sectors and hover effect.
        </p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my Titanium code for the WebView

```
var win_rptWebView  = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Web View',});
var webviewEx = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'chart.html'}); 
win_rptWebView.add(webviewEx);
```

How do i render the g.raphael chart on the WebView in Titanium?  Are there tutorials on how to do this (g.raphael chart + titanium)  the more simple the explanation the better. I am a new Titanium and g.Raphael user so I apologize in advance if it looks simple to others.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

you may be having encountering this bug here:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-961

The solution is to rename the javascript files you are including (raphael files) to have a .jsf file extension.